# Redirecting after an axios post in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm having trouble finding information about redirecting

What I would like to happen is after filing out the form the user hits submit then it fires off the axios.post request and after posting it redirects to a different page

I'm using Router V5 to set up the site routs

The post is working to my mysql db

I have my form component in a function and using useState and setState hooks

I'm not using redux for this project

```js
  const sendToDB = async (photo, data) => {
    const item = {
      style_name: data.itemName,
      category: data.category,
      color: data.color,
      small_qty: data.small_qty,
      med_qty: data.med_qty,
      large_qty: data.large_qty,
      price: data.price,
      description: data.about,
      state_id: creator.stateId,
      artistId: creator.id,
      image: photo.pic,
    };
    console.log(item);
    axios.post("/api/items", item).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      //Redirct to shop page???
      //Path to="/shop"
    });
  };
```

Comment: Okay so both answers worked, but I had to put it outside after my axios "then" statement. Which I feel is something I did wrong with my code. But it is sending before redirecting, so I'll keep on working on it! But thanks @Nick !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `useHistory` hook and then `push` the new location.

```js
const history = useHistory();

...

axios.post("/api/items", item).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  history.push("/shop");
});
```

Comment: So I imported useHistory from react-router-dom.
Set const history = useHistory() inside at the top of my function.
Then put the history.push("/shop") inside my axios post then statement and it wasn't working.
I also tried to console logging history in the "then" statement and it wasn't returning anything.
But it is returning the console.log(res)


`axios.post("/api/items", item).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(history);
      history.push("/shop");
      console.log(history);
    });
  };`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `default state` to oversee **redirection** with the use of `useEffect` hook:-

```js
const [isRedirect, setIsRedirect] = useState(false)
const history = useHistory();

...

axios.post("/api/items", item).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  setIsRedirect(true)
});

// redirect user upon succession
useEffect(() => {
  (() => {
    if(isRedirect) {
      history.push("/shop");
    }
  })()
}, [isRedirect])
```